# Is such a function possible?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I just came across this problem: Let $f:\mathbb R\to (0,+\infty)$ be differentiable. Suppose that $f'$ has no zero. If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$, then what is $\lim_{x\to 0}(\csc f(x))^{f(x)}$?

I'm not having a problem with computing the limit. Given that $f'$ has no zero and $f$ is differentiable (hence continuous on its entire domain $\mathbb R$), $f$ must be strictly monotone. Let's first assume $f$ is strictly increasing. Here's the problem: if $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$, then what can $f$ be when $x<0$? Intuitively speaking, when $f(x)$ already approaches zero when $x$ approaches zero, $f$ cannot further decrease when $x$ further decreases (since the range is $(0,+\infty)$). Similarly if we assume $f$ is strictly decreasing, then there seems to be no possible values for $f$ to take on when $x>0$. Does such a function exist, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should double-check your problem. It doesn’t make sense if $f$ is defined at zero (hence, since it is continuous there, $f(0)=0$, a contradiction).

Comment: @Mindlack makes sense. Thanks!